# JavaFX - How to open a new stage in same window?

Tags: javafx, modal-dialog, stage

I'm a beginner, I don't know how to open a new `stage` in same window in javaFX8?

```
Stage modal_stage = new Stage();
modal_stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 575));
modal_stage.setTitle("modal");
modal_stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
modal_stage.initOwner(modal_stage.getOwner());
modal_stage.setResizable(false);
modal_stage.show();
```

When I opened a new `stage` through the above code, the `stage` always opening in a difference window,like this:

[image]

But I want the new stage will not create a new icon in StartMenu taskbar, just like Swing's Dialog of Jframe---No matter how many dialogs I open under jframe, It is always displayed as one window. So what can I do?
Sorry, I am not very good at English, I wish I had clarified the question.

Comment: You need to set the owner of the new stage to the existing stage. `modalStage.initOwner(modalStage.getOwner())` doesn't do anything (you're effectively doing `owner = owner`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a parent stage:

```
Stage parentStage = new Stage();
```

And the child Stage:

```
Stage childStage = new Stage();
```

You have to set the init owner of the childStage to be the parent:

```
childStage.initOwner(parent);
```

Mention that the above has to be called before the `childStage` to be shown.

Also mention that doing this you will have some behaviour like when `parent` child is minimized then `childStage` will be also minimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I rewrite the code like this:"modal_stage.initOwner(main_stage);", it's working!

Comment: Thank you, no double stage in task bar